# Publish yeoman-generator. Does not publish bover.json and .bowerrc

Tags: npm, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator, bower-install

I'm trying to publish my yeoman generator into npmjs. At the root of my generator I have bower.json and .bowerrc, but after the publication I try to install my generator and these files do not exist.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
into package.json remove

```
"files": [
  "app" ],
```